# Is it necessary to use HTTP Server to use socket.io with node / What are its advantages

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, socket.io

On the socket.io webpage the server example of using socket.io as a cross browser websocket is simple:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function () { });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () { });
});
```

However, most all of the examples I see of socket.io being used include a web server such as express or node's built in 'http' module.  I have been using socket.io on my local machine, but I am wondering what the advantages  of using an http server with socket.io is and when it would be necessary?

Comment: there are no advantages, when using socket.io like that in your example it creates the http server instance on that port, only to serve socket.io hanshake. The difference when using express and not http module is simple, there is no difference because socket.io bind an http instance, under express its raw http module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Websocket requests and HTTP requests are different things (even though they may look similar) and require different servers to handle them.  If all you want to do is handle websocket traffic, then your example is totally fine.  However, most projects that involve websockets do so as part of a larger web application that also handles regular HTTP traffic (to server HTML and static files to a browser, handle REST API calls, etc.) so you'll often see the two servers (HTTP and Websocket) working together.  A common example of this is to use Express and Socket.io as a complete HTTP+Websockets solution.

Comment: Great, however, the socket.io documentation shows that it will make an http server for you if you do not specify one (using the built in or other node module).  Is this server as robust as node's core HTTP server?

Comment: If you just specify a port, Socket.io will spin up an internal instance of the core Node HTTP server.  So it's every bit as robust as one you would start yourself when it comes to handling connections.  However, the server instance isn't exposed to your code, so you can't do things like bind events to it.  That's why you'll see most web apps spinning up their own servers and just feeding them to Socket.io.